# jquery remove corresponsing selection checkbox/radio button on click of a DIV

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick, radio-button

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3qD4/1/

`$("#testDiv").html("");`

Here I am trying to remove the selection (radio & checkbox) on click of the remove.png click beside each item. Is there a way in jquery to get the corresponsing radio/checkbox name, reverse engineer and remove the checkbox/radio selection? I also need to remove the item from my testDiv on this remove.png click(which be a 'x' mark). Tried selecting the element but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're adding the `.bckeys` dynamically, you'll need to use `on()` and delegate the event. You can use the `text()` of the added element to target the `label`, then traverse using `prev()` to uncheck the corresponding `input`:

```
$('#testDiv').on('click', '.bckeys', function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $('label[title=' + $this.text() + ']').prev('input').prop('checked', false);
   $this.remove();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3qD4/11/)

Also, make sure you remove those duplicate IDs :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was trying to do, but it doesn't seem to work for a radio button, my other js functions are working when I specify 'input' but here it is not...

Comment: @user1022521 I don't know why it wouldn't work. Could you create another fiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: New fiddle where I have the issue: jsfiddle.net/d3qD4/20

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to the image which corresponds to the respective checkbox id. Then simply use that id to figure out which checkbox value you want to set to unchecked.

Something like : If checkbox id is "check1" .. you can name image id as image_check1  or something

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
    $(":checkbox").change(function () {

    $("#testDiv").html("")
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        $("#testDiv").append($("<span/>", {
            class: 'bckeys',
            html: $(this).next().text().trim() + "<img id=" + $(this).next().attr("title") + " src='" + "http://www.test.com" + "' src='remove.png'>"

        }))

    })

});

$(document).on("click", "img", function () {
    $("[title=" + this.id + "]").prev().toggle();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3qD4/8/)